# Session or cache problems with Liferay

Tags: liferay, jboss5.x

I used jboss 5.1 with liferay 5.2.3.

I have a big problem with Liferay Sessions i think.
It could also be a caching problem.

The problem is that (sometimes!) I can see the dock of another person that has logged in a short time ago ( so able to get this very private information ).

meaning Sometimes, an User A see User B's page.

we used proxy in the network in front of the application server.

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

First, determine where the problem is. If you have steps to reproduce try first with the web payer and then without it hitting JBoss directly. This will tell you where you should look for a problem.

If it will be on the web layer, you probably enabled too aggressive caching and should loosen it. Cache only js, css and img.

If the problem is on the Liferay side then look at the caching filter. Also, check if JBoss does not have some additional caching.

BTW: 5.2.3 is a 10+ years old version with security holes all over the place. Hope you are not using it for something more serious then hello world :D